# How to re-render on change to nested array?

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
struct Clip {

    let url: URL

    var images = [CGImage?]()
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var clips = [Clip]()
}

struct Preview: View {

    var clips: [Clip]

    var body: some View {

        ForEach (clips, id: \.url) { clip in

            HStack {

                ForEach (clip.images, id: \.self) { i in

                    (i == nil ?
                        Image(systemName: "forward.fill") :
                        Image(decorative: i!, scale: 1))
                            .resizable()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Preview` updates when a new item is added to `ViewModel.clips` but not when a new element is added to `Clip.images` or if `Clip.images` is reassigned.

How can I get this view to re-render when the `images` nested array is updated?

Comment: Would you provide reproducible example?

Comment: I fixed it. Please see my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by changing `clip` to an observable object...

```
class Clip: ObservableObject {

    let url: URL

    init(url: URL) {

        self.url = url
    }

    @Published var images = [CGImage?]()
}
```

And splitting the view into two...

```
struct Preview: View {

    var clips: [Clip]

    var body: some View {

        HStack {

            ForEach (clips, id: \.url) {

                PreviewClip(clip: $0)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PreviewClip: View {

    @ObservedObject var clip: Clip

    var body: some View {

        HStack {

            ForEach (clip.images, id: \.self) { i in

                (i == nil ?
                    Image(systemName: "forward.fill") :
                    Image(decorative: i!, scale: 1))
                        .resizable()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully, the performance is ok.

This is the code that updates the images, which runs in a closure the runs when an asset is loaded.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

    clip.images = []
}

LibraryService.createPreview(url: urlAsset.url) { i in

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        clip.images.append(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the correct way to do it; However, you can still have a `ViewModel` to hold the arrays of clips, just like what you had in your question.

Comment: I think the reason it worked was not because you made `Clip` an `ObservableObject`, but rather because you made it into a `class`, which is passed by reference. What's not clear in your code, is how you are updating the values, and that's probably where the problem lies

Comment: @NewDev It doesn't work without `Clip` being an `ObservableObject`. I've added the update code to my answer.

Comment: @MuhandJumah Do you mean that the inner view isn't necessary?

Comment: @IanWarburton oh no, its necessary to have, its good. I just meant the `ViewModel` that you removed could have stayed for modularity; However, you are 100% fine doing it this way.

Comment: @MuhandJumah Ah, I didn't remove it. I didn't show it in the answer because I didn't change it. :)

Comment: Got it! my apologies!